# Why does my Component, which I create several times, just mount once in total (componentDidMount)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**Brief description**

I have a simple weather app made with react / redux that renders a table with 3 charts and a google map component per Row. 
The problem lies in this google map component. It only mounts once and I don't get why.

**Expected Behaviour**

When I add a new city to the weather table it should get me the new data from the city and display a google map with the city. The other cities I previously added should also be displayed with their corresponding location.

**Actual Behaviour**

Everything is fine with the first city I add. I see the map, and the charts. 
Let's take for example the city 'Linz'. 
Now when I add a second city (a 2nd row) for example 'Salzburg', the row gets added, the charts display the correct data, but the map is the same as the first one (Linz). And I can now add as many as I want the map is always the same eg. 'Linz'. I also found the solution but I can't figure out why the problem exists. More details to follow

**The troublemaker component**

Here is a snippet of the component that renders said map (it just get's passed in a long and lat as props):

```
export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {

    const city = {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.long };

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
        zoom: 12,
        center: city
    })

}

render() {
return <div className='map' ref={'map'} />

}
```

}

The problem here is, that the component just mounts one time per app use (no matter how often I will update the map eg. add cities). 
If I add the `componentDidUpdate()` method to the map component the app functions like it should:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const city = {lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.long };

    const map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
        zoom: 12,
        center: city
    })
}
```

**Screenshots with and without componentDidUpdate()**

With just `componentDidMount()`:

[image]

With the added `componentDidUpdate()`:

[image]

**The Question**

*Why? Why is it just mounting one time, when I create several "instances" of this component?* I call the map component like this:

- First I map through an array from redux store that has weather data, one per city so it start's empty
- For every weather data in the array I call this function:

  renderWeather = (weather, id) => {

  ```
  const temperatures = weather.list.map((data) => data.main.temp);
  const pressures = weather.list.map((data) => data.main.pressure);
  const humidities = weather.list.map((data) => data.main.humidity);
  let long = weather.city.coord.lon;
  let lat = weather.city.coord.lat;

  return (
      <tr key={id} className='row'>
          <td> <GoogleMap long={long} lat={lat} /> </td>
          <td> 
              <Chart color='green' data={temperatures} />
          </td>
          <td> <Chart color='red' data={pressures} /> </td>
          <td> <Chart color='orange' data={humidities} /> </td>
      </tr>
  )
  ```

  }

So when I have 2 cities (array length of 2) it should create 2 pieces of the `GoogleMap` Component? So every Component should run the `componentDidUpdate` right? But it does it just once? Can you please help me to understand why this isn't working as I expected it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's working on componentDidUpdate, I'm guessing there's some api call for {long, lat} data, that is resolving after the component mounts.

**Edit:**

change your [WeatherRedux/src/actions/index.js](https://github.com/dhuber666/WeatherRedux/tree/master/src)

```
export function fetchWeather(city) {

    const url = `${BASE_URL}&q=${city}, AT`;

    const weatherPromise = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: weatherPromise
    }
}
```

to something like this,

```
export function fetchWeather(city) {

    const url = `${BASE_URL}&q=${city}, AT`;

    axios.get(url).then(function(data){
      return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: data
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I used Redux-Promise as middleware. I call the open weather api in my fetchWeather action. The reducers gets the retrieved weather data and saves it into the store (weather).

The main component `weather-table` is wired up with the redux stores and receives weather via props (the connect function). 

Here is the whole project: https://github.com/dhuber666/WeatherRedux if you want to take a look. Thx!

Comment: Hi that's the point of redux-promise. With the code like your wrote it the action creator returns nothing. And if I return the get request it returns the whole expression and not an object with type and payload props like it has to. That's where the redux-promise library comes into play because it handles this for you. But thank you for trying to help me!